# Datatables DOM Horizontal Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables

I am trying to put the feature elements of the bootstrap datatable pagination side by side.

[image: See picture for reference]

But the result shows that the feature elements are aligned vertically.

[image: here]

How do I align the feature elements horizontally?

**js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#executives').DataTable({
      "dom": '<"top"lpf>t<"bottom"lpi><"clear">'
    });
  });
```

**html:**

```
        <table class="table table-striped" id="executives">
            <thead>
            <tr id="myTable">
                <th>Customer Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Comment: Take a look at the approach I used [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63855033/12567365) to a similar question. You should be able to adapt that to your specific needs.

Comment: @andrewjames this actually helped me! Thanks!